xmlsec.Error: (1, 'cannot load key') while loading the private key
I am using xmlsec package for importing the X509 Key.
I have a X509 private in a file and trying to use the below code to load the private key. However i am getting the xmlsec.Error: (1, 'cannot load key'). I tried multiple ways. nothing is working and more over the error message is not detailed enough to try other options.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.
import xmlsec
with open('private_key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    key_data = key_file.read()
xmlsec.Key.from_memory(key_data, xmlsec.constants.KeyDataFormatPem)

My PEM file format is as shown below:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea TUlkjshduahdajsduaydjaudhswmb7ajwesdajhassdadasdsdaeddasdaeqdea asdadasd==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----


@PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you. Updated the code. I want to know what is the format of the pem file that xml.Key.from_memory function is expecting? There are good examples on web.

Cannot reproduce. Perhaps your file private_key.pem is corrupted. To be clear, I succesfully read in a PKCS8, unencrypted, PEM-formatted RSA private key file with xmlsec.Key.from_memory() and it returned an xmlsec.Key object without any error messages.

Thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk. I was able to use the same private key and able to generate the signed key in java code. can you share the format of the key? I tried with the format that I mentioned in the description.
